# git checkout while running another program at the background

Tags: git

I just have a dumb question about using `git`.

Say, I am on `current_branch`, and I am running lengthy `program A`, this will continuously generate some log files and save onto my `current_branch`.

This run will be taking about ~5 hours. **DURING** the run, can I do switch into another branch (let's call this `new_branch`) and do my work?

My question is, what happen to the files being generated by `program A` that runs on the `current_branch`, if I switch to `new_branch` at the middle of the run?

Answer (score 5):

> *My question is, what happen to the files being generated by program A that runs on the current_branch, if I switch to new_branch at the middle of the run?*

There's no magic here. If you switch to a new branch the changed files in your working directory will change and your program will continue along with those new files. Any ignored files like temp files, log files, and so on, will be ignored by Git. What happens next depends on your program and operating system.

Any code your program has already loaded will remain loaded. For many programs this is sufficient, but some systems will dynamically load files as needed, and they may not all be loaded. Others may detect that the underlying files have changed and reload their code. Again, there's no magic. If your program goes to open a checked in file after you switch branches it will get the new version of the file.

On Unix operating systems, if a file is moved or deleted any open filehandles will remain open. That means if, for example, your program has an open filehandle to a log file and that log file is deleted or moved it will continue to write to that file. This is a technique for securing temp files, create a temp file, open it for read and write, delete the file (which is really just a pointer to the actual data), and keep filehandle open. Once the program exits and all filehandles close the data will be cleaned up. However, it's unlikely you're keeping log files checked into Git.

Windows can have mandatory file locking. This means if you have a filehandle open to a file and try to move or delete it, you will not be allowed to do so. So if you're on Windows this means you may not be able to check out the new branch.

---

The simplest and safest thing is to not risk any of this. Make a fresh clone in a new directory to develop on while your long running process is running. If it's large you can clone your existing repository rather than pulling it across a network. Work in exactly the same way as you would. When the long process is finished, you can either set this temporary repo as a remote and pull its changes from it, or make the simple expedient of deleting the old repo and moving the new one in its place. Git repositories are just directories and can be moved freely.

In the future, don't run real code on your development checkout. Instead, make a fresh clone and do your long running processes in that. Whether that's in another directory or a dedicated worker server is up to you.

Comment: Another option is to use `git worktree` which will basically create a clone of the repo to another path.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what will happen, think about Git's model and the way Git uses your computer's file system.  Then think about how the program you are running uses your computer's file system.  Some details depend on your operating system.

First, let's look at Git's model.  In a Git repository:

- We find the repository's databases (DBs).  Git stores these in a directory named `.git`.  There are multiple DBs (largely just *key-value stores* in database terms), but the main one stores Git's *objects*—commits and all the support items needed to work with them—and the second-most important one stores names.

  This second DB translates from names, such as branch names like `master`, to Git hash IDs, which are those big ugly 40-character strings such as `e3331758f12da22f4103eec7efe1b5304a9be5e9`.  The hash IDs are themselves keys in the first store: each key enables Git to find the corresponding object.  If the object is a commit, as this one is (it's a commit in the Git repository for Git), the value that goes with that hash ID eventually enables Git to find all the files that are snapshotted in that commit.

  Committed files are frozen: they can never be changed.  You can access them from now until forever, at least as long as the commit itself remains in the main repository database.  They are stored in a special compressed—often very highly compressed—format, and if the same file appears multiple times, there is only one copy of that file's data.  This is possible because they are read-only!  You cannot change a stored file (nor any existing commit, for that matter).  Being in this special Git-only format, most programs cannot deal with these files at all.
- Next, we have a thing that Git variously calls the *index*, the *staging area*, or the *cache*.  This thing—it's mostly just one file, `.git/index`—is a bit complicated internally but its essential job is to keep track of (i.e., "index") your work-tree.  It contains, indirectly, a copy of every file that is active now.  More precisely, it contains every *tracked* file.  In fact, this is the very definition of a tracked file: it's a file that is in the index.

  The files stored in the index are also in the special Git-only format.  Unlike committed files, however, they are *not* read-only: you can replace the index copy at any time.  This is what `git add` does: it overwrites the index copy with the work-tree version.  Hence, the index always contains what you are proposing to put in your *next* commit.

  When you run `git commit`, Git simply packages up (and freezes) the index's files into a new commit.  This is why Git is so much faster than most of its related version control systems: the index is already pretty close to a completed commit.  Git does not have to spend a lot of time repackaging all your work-tree files: they're already in the index, in the right form.
- Last, we have a *work-tree*.  Here, you have your files in your computer's ordinary form.  This lets you work on and with them.

Git does not actually *need* a work-tree to get its job done.  It's not Git, it's the *human* (and the various computer programs that don't read special Git-only format files) that need the the work-tree.

Git allows you (the human and/or the computer) to keep additional files in the work-tree that you won't commit.  You do this by simply not copying those files into the index.  If they are not in the index, they are *untracked*, and won't be in the next commit you make—they're not in the proposed commit now, so they won't be in the actual commit later, unless you first copy the files into the index.

#### With the above in mind, `git checkout` becomes easily explained

To perform a `git checkout`, Git needs to:

- See what's in the work-tree right now.  It can do so pretty quickly by scanning the index, which keeps track of what's in the work-tree (except for untracked files).  If you have not modified the index with `git add`, the index matches the currently-checked-out commit.  If you *have* modified the index, Git can easily tell that you have, since Git is what is maintaining the index.
- See what you *want* to have in the work-tree based on the commit you're checking out.  Many files may be exactly the same in the *current* commit as in the proposed checkout.  (At this point Git has to be careful, since you may have changed the work-tree content *without* having run `git add`.)
- For any file that is different, or new, or removed, Git must now extract the appropriate file from the commit you want to switch-to, and replace (or add or remove) that file from the work-tree.  Git can first check to make sure this won't clobber anything you are working on.  Git *doesn't* have to check any files that are the same in the current commit, and the proposed new one.

If the checkout should proceed, Git will now copy the desired commit—or at least, any different files—into the index, so that the index matches the commit, and into the work-tree, so that the work-tree matches the commit as well.  The desired commit is now the current commit, and the index and work-tree are ready to be changed / updated if and when you want to make changes and commit.

#### Other programs generally skip `.git` entirely and look only at the work-tree

Unless you are working with a program that intimately understands the inner workings of Git—which is not a good idea as these evolve over time—the program itself should just work with the work-tree files.  These are managed by the operating system in its usual way, whatever that is.

If you run `git checkout` while some program is running, `git checkout` will (try to) modify the work-tree, just as we noted above.  If that works, well, that's no problem for Git: it's up to this long-running program to deal with the change.  You need to consult that program to see what it does.  If modifying the work-tree *fails*, the checkout also fails, which is mostly OK for Git, which just keeps you on your original commit.

There are some potential corner cases here though: perhaps Git has checked everything up front and thinks it will succeed, gets partway through the checkout, has some step fail, and tries to back out of everything (to restore the original commit) but has the *backing out* fail as well.  In this case, your index and work-tree can become out of sync.  This is not fatal for Git, but it is a pain for *you* to deal with afterward, as your work-tree is [neither fish nor fowl](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neither_fish_nor_fowl).

For the most part, it's generally wiser (as [Schwern answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51412032/1256452)) to just use a fresh work-tree.