# What happens when you change branches while running a background process?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash

Say I have two bash terminals open in the same git repository on branch `main`.

In the one, I start some process that takes a while to run, storing the results in a subdirectory `/data` every 2 seconds.

Then, in the other window, I call `git checkout otherbranch` to change branches.

Will the first window continue the rest of the process on the first branch, storing all results in `/data` on `main`, then switch branches on completion? Or will the first chunk of the results be written to `/data` on `main`, while others are written to `/data` on `otherbranch`?

Comment: Git does not promise *not* to `rm -rf ./data` during the `git checkout otherbranch` (depending on conditions). If it does so, your output files may be lost. Git's checkout code strives to do as few file-system operations as possible for *speed* purposes, though, so depending on what files, if any, it needs to *replace* in `./data`, you might get away with this. The short answer is: for safety, don't do it.

Comment: [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2048470/1256452) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51411897/1256452) questions...

Answer (score 0):

> Will the first window continue the rest of the process on the first branch, storing all results in `/data` on `main`, then switch branches on completion?

Yes, the process started in the first terminal will continue. However, depending on whether the files stored in `/data` are previously tracked by Git or not, one of two things will happen:

1. If the files are *new*, they will appear in the working directory as *untracked*.
2. If the files are *tracked*, Git might refuse to switch branch if those files have conflicting changes in `otherbranch`. If not, they will simply appear as *modified* in the working directory.

In any case, it's important to point out that Git doesn't store files in branches, but rather in [tree structures](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#_tree_objects) referenced by individual commits. This means that the files in `/data` won't become part of either branch until you commit them.